# Возможно ли расшифровать трафик TCP/TLS?

Tags: веб-программирование, сокет, криптография, tcp, tls

Есть одна софтина на компьютере. Название ввиду некоторых её особенностей озвучить не могу. Суть в том, что я хочу поснифать запросы, которые она отправляет на сервер. Сложностей добавляет то, что программа каким-то образом обходит все сниффера типа fiddler, charles и тд. (ставлю на то, что из-за того, что общается по сокетам). Получилось лишь узнать лишь адрес сервера с помощью Echo Mirage. Попробовал через Wireshark увидел летящие запросы, handshak`и и тд. Вопрос теперь стоит в расшифровке идущего трафика. Программа не пишет логи в SSLKEYLOGFILE. Единственное что удалось узнать это Cipther Suite: tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_chacha20_poly1305_sha256. Есть ли какие-нибудь способы расшифровать этот трафик ? Прошу прощения за большое количество воды. Пытался максимально точно описать ситуацию.

Comment: Ну, TLS именно для того и существует, чтобы трафик нельзя было расшифровать) Если программа сама не предоставляет ключи для расшифровки, то, подозреваю, придётся влезать в её память для поиска этих самых ключей

Comment: под линукс ltrace может ... на каком языке программа?

Comment: Клиент на C#, но почти все функции берет из их библиотеки на C++. Клиент пытался ковырять. Ни один деобфускатор не берёт.

Comment: можно попробовать посмотреть, какие данные передаются в библиотечные вызовы. *trace, Как точно -- не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую